Where to add 3rd party service providers in Laravel 11?
I'm using https://tenancyforlaravel.com/ to test in a fresh laravel 11 installation.
I'm stuck at the following part:
enter image description here
Link: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/installation
I've setup everything but the new database is not being created when I create a new tenant and domain.
However, my database connection is fine, as it inserts the tenant and domain records.
I've tried the online forums answers, but there was not enough support available.

I was not adding the TenentServiceProvidedr in config/app.php (providers array)
Now everything is working fine!!
